# App description update on play store

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I want to update the description of the app plus the screenshots on play store but the app remains the same viz same version number(I don't want to publish new app since nothing in app is changed)

Is that possible or will google ask for app to be updated as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about play store user interface

Comment: No its not about store user interface and there is no information about such a scenario on google play terms so had to ask on stackoverflow and it has been well answered

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can update the description and can change screenshot also and your app will remain same only the description and screen will be updated within two hours, and you don't need to update apk.

google will never ask to update the apk file when you change description or distribution. below is the screen shot where yoiu have to edit description and change screen shot.[image]

Answer (score 46):

This is how you can update the description in Google Play console **New UI August 2020**

Store presence -> Main store listing

[image: Screenshot for google play console new UI]

Comment: I changed it two or three days back, but it doesn't get updated on both Play Store and Web.

Comment: Don't worry it may take some time especially during the current hard time because or COVID-19  @InamUlHuq

Comment: Sure, let's see.

Comment: I changed description and get updated on Web, but not get update on Play Store.

Comment: It will take small time and updated also in play store on phone, don't worry

Answer (score 23):

**Using this [keywords] Search app in play store easliy**

**Link:-**

https://play.google.com/apps/publish

[image]

You can edit the app description and screenshots without updating the application itself. Just go to "Store Listing" in the Android developer console, make your changes, and save them.

Comment: Using this Search app in play store easliy

Answer (score 7):

You can edit the app description and screenshots without updating the application itself. Just go to "Store Listing" in the Android developer console, make your changes, and save them.

Answer (score 7):

As of June 2022, `Store presence` -> `Main store` listing is no longer the last step. Then you need to go to `Publishing overview` => `Send for review`

1. First do as described by @AmrDeveloper in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63350488
2. Then this screenshot:

[image: steps to submit store listing changes]

Comment: For me, I see that it was automatically Sent for Review, I never clicked this. Has been 2 days, and is under review yet. Google's documentation says that it might take upto 7 days. Really slows the process down. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?visit_id=637995093368676531-3224005979&rd=1

Comment: The store list changes needs to be published explicitly otherwise changes wont reflect

Comment: FWIW, the Google Play Console is a top 5 worst UI of all time for me. I log in there and literally have no idea what is being presented to me.

Answer (score 4):

Within Play Developer Console click on the app, then choose Store Presence then Store Listing on the left side menu and you'll be able to edit your short and long descriptions.