# Is it possible to set the description of application on google play store based on country/region?

Tags: android, localization, region, google-play-console

I wanted to have description of my android app based on country/region. By that I meant, I have my app trademarked in my country so when someone try to download the app from here, I wish them to see the trade mark. While when some one outside my country wants to download it, this trade mark should not be visible.

I know there a way to set description based on language from store listing but it does not address my issue because, if someone outside my country has set the default language in their set as that of my country then he/she will be able to see my trade mark.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this behavior.

I found something related to description update here [App description update on play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436865/app-description-update-on-play-store) but it is not helpful for me.

Any help on this regards will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Have a look at [this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9156429?hl=en-GB), "Create custom store listings to target specific countries"

> 1. Sign in to your Play Console.
> 2. Select an app.
> 3. On the left menu, click Store presence > Custom store listing. 
>      If you don’t already have a main store listing for your app, you need to create one and publish your app before you can create a custom store listing.